# Deleting an entire line in a file that contains a certain string

Tags: bash

I'm interested in figuring out a way to delete an entire line in a text file that contains a particular string.  This will be for a text file that operates like a phone book containing names, address, phone numbers, etc

[Ex]

John Smith, 123 Fake St, 555-555-555

I want to know how I can search for a particular name and remove the entire line that contains it.  So for the example above, I would search for "John" or "Smith" or "John Smith" and remove the entire line that contains those words.

Would I used grep, or sed for this?  I want it to make a permanent change to the file

Comment: I hope that was a joke....

Comment: it was not. and you should not post someone else's data so I was warning

Answer (score 1):

You could use `d` command from `sed`.

To remove all lines containing word John, you would do

```
sed --in-place /John/d ./file
```

In case of Multiple criterions, use the `-e` command

```
sed --in-place -e '/John/d; /John Smith/d' ./file
```